# Why do hyperkaehler manifolds have complex structure valued in a 2-sphere?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, quaternions, symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I understand that hyperkaehler manifolds have almost quaternionic structure, whereby there are three complex structures $I,J$ and $K$ which satisfy 
$$
I^2=J^2=K^2=IJK=-1.
$$
It is also said that 
$aI+bJ+cK$ is also a complex structure, so long as 
$$
a^2+b^2+c^2=1,
$$
where $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$.
This last requirement implies that the complex structure of a hyperkaehler manifold is valued in a 2-sphere. But what is the reason we have this last requirement on the parameters $a,b$ and $c$?

Comment: In case it matters, I think most mathematicians would not say the complex structure is valued in a sphere, but instead that _there is a $2$-sphere's worth of complex structures_. :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. What is the difference exactly?

Comment: To say some function or field $f$ on a space $X$ is "valued in the $2$-sphere" usually connotes that to each point of $X$ is associated a point $f(x)$ in the $2$-sphere (i.e., $f:X \to S^{2}$ is a mapping). Here, by contrast, for each point $(a, b, c)$ of the $2$-sphere there is a complex structure $aI + bJ + cK$ (i.e., there is a mapping from $S^{2}$ to the space of complex structures on the hyperkaehler manifold).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Consider a general endomorphism of the form $L := a I + b J + c K$. Then, if $L$ is a complex structure, we must have $$-1 = L^2 = (a I + b J + c K)^2 = a^2 I^2 + ab IJ + ac IK + ab JI + \cdots .$$ We can deduce from the defining equation that $I, J, K$ all anticommute, i.e., satisfy $IJ = -JI$, etc., so we can see above that the contribution of the second and fourth terms together is $$ab IJ + ab JI = ab IJ + ab (-IJ) = 0 ,$$ and by symmetry the terms in $J, K$ and $K, I$ similarly vanish. On the other hand, since, e.g., $I$ is a complex structure, we have $I^2 = -1$, and likewise for $J, K$. Putting this all together and clearing signs gives the condition.

Comment: Would the downvoter explain their objection?

Answer (score 5):

Note that

\begin{align*}
& (aI + bJ + cK)(aI + bJ + cK)\\ 
=&\ a^2I^2 + abIJ + acIK + abJI + b^2J^2 + bcJK + acKI + bcKJ + c^2K^2\\
=&\ -a^2\operatorname{id} + abIJ + acIK - abIJ -b^2\operatorname{id} + bcJK -acIK - bcJK - c^2\operatorname{id}\\
=&\ -(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)\operatorname{id}.
\end{align*}

So $aI + bJ + cK$ is an almost complex structure if and only if $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$.